# Data fixtures no loading symfony 4

Tags: php, database, symfony, fixtures

hello community I have a question I create the data fixtures in Symfony 4 when I send to the base I have this error: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (22/10/2009) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character:

```
   my class: 
   class AppDataFixtures extends fixture
   {






/**
 * Load data fixtures with the passed EntityManager
 *
 * @param ObjectManager $manager
 */
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $this->loadUsers($manager);

}


private function loadUsers(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    foreach ($this->getUserData() as [$name, $username, $email, $birthdate, $password, $address, $userCode, $roles, $isActive]) {
        $user = new User();
        $user->setName($name);
        $user->setUsername($username);
        $user->setEmail($email);
        $user->setBirthdate($birthdate);
        $user->setPassword($this->passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $password));
        $user->setAddress($address);
        $user->setUserCode($userCode);
        $user->setRoles($roles);

        $manager->persist($user);

    }
    $manager->flush();
}



private function getUserData(): array
{

    return [
        // $userData = [$name, $username, $email, $birthday, $password, $adress, $userCode, $roles, $isActiv];
        ['Jane Doe', 'jane_admin', 'jane_admin@symfony.com', new \DateTime('12/10/2008'),'test', '45 rue de tourtille', 1398799, ['ROLE_USER'], true],
        ['Tom Doe', 'tom_admin', 'tom_admin@symfony.com', new \DateTime('22/10/2009'),'test','46 rue de tourtille', 13587999, ['ROLE_USER'], true],
        ['John Doe', 'john_user', 'john_user@symfony.com', new \DateTime('15/11/2000'),'test','43 rue de tourtille', 139798999, ['ROLE_USER'], true]
    ];
}
```

}

Help me, please

Comment: Maybe change the date format, 12/10/2008 to 2008-10-12

Comment: It ok, thank you very much

Comment: where there are associations I have to do a foreach   Expected value of type "App\Entity\Game" for association field "App\Entity\
  GamePlayer#$game", got "string" instead

Comment: I add my comment in the answer

Comment: You can share objects between Fixtures, check here https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html chapter "Sharing Objects between Fixtures"

Answer (score 0):

Change the date format, 12/10/2008 to 2008-10-12